# Best way to terminate a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a downloader which downloads multiple files simultaneously. Each download has its own Form which runs the downloading code in a thread. I'm looking for the best approach to terminate the running download threads for two reasons

- The download is cancelled by the user
- The main form is closed

So far there are three approaches

1. Use a check variable like `bool terminate`
2. Use `Thread.Abort()`
3. Run the thread is a `AppDomain` and unload the `AppDomain` to terminate

Problem with the first approach is that threads keeps running until it hits the `if` statement. Even if the `MainForm` is closed the process keeps on running until all the downloading threads are terminated.

I don't know much about `Thread.Abort` but it is highly discouraged.

Here is the code for the last approach:

```
public class Processor : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private AsyncOperation _operation;

    private AppDomain Domain { get; set; }

    public delegate void ProgressChangedEventHnadler(Processor sender, int progress);

    public delegate void ProcessedEventHandler(Processor sender, EventArgs e);

    public delegate void ExceptionOccuredEventHandler(Processor sender, Exception ex);

    public event ProgressChangedEventHnadler ProgressChanged;

    public event ProcessedEventHandler Processed;

    public event ExceptionOccuredEventHandler ExceptionOccured;

    private void OnProgressChanged(int progress)
    {
        if(ProgressChanged!=null)
            ProgressChanged.Invoke(this,progress);
    }

    private void OnProcessed(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Processed != null)
            Processed.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnExceptionOccured(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ExceptionOccured != null)
            ExceptionOccured.Invoke(this,ex);
    }

    public Processor()
    {
        _operation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    }

    public static Processor CreateInstance()
    {
        var locaion = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var instance =(Processor)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(locaion, typeof (Processor).FullName);
        instance.Domain = domain;
        return instance;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var mainThread = new Thread(Process);
        mainThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        AppDomain.Unload(Domain);
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        //Do the Work and raise events like 
        //_operation.Post(e => OnProcessed((EventArgs)e), EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define *Best*.  The quickest?  The most resilient?  Nicest to the Thread?

Comment: The most efficient in every expect which is nicest to thread and terminates the threads immediately so if the mainform is closed all the threads are immediately terminated

Comment: Set `IsBackground` to `true` on your threads...

Comment: That was so simple. what about when user cancels just one download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you have two options:

- allow the thread to terminate itself. This covers your first option.
- terminate the thread externally. This covers your other options.

And that's it. And none of them, in general, can prevent the threads from running for indefinite time after they *should* (from the programmer's intent point of view) terminate.

The most *predictable* approach is the first one. If terminating takes too long, try to do the processing in smaller steps to allow checking the termination flag more frequently. Also, note the [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) flag which will help with the application being unable to close itself.

The whole problem with the other options is that *any* code (except for some special cases like `finally` blocks) can be just interrupted in the middle of its execution, which can lead to some undesired results (e.g. some unmanaged resources not released) - as it is explained in [`Thread.Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation.

Note that the third approach in the newest versions of .NET framework is equivalent to calling the `Abort` method on your executing threads, as explained in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The threads in domain are terminated using the `Abort` method, which throws a `ThreadAbortException` in the thread. Although the thread should terminate promptly, it can continue executing for an unpredictable amount of time in a finally clause.

So it seems better to use `Thread.Abort` from these two, as it's simpler and more readable.

If the first approach is problematic, and if you are well aware of the type of operations your thread is executing and there is no problem in interrupting them in-between then the "brutal" approach should be fine.

Comment: mainly the code consists of HttpWebRequests which depends upon the timeout value so the first approach is probably not the best. Should i go with Thread.Abort or the last one?

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem I've just edited the post. They are equivalent as far as this issue is concerned, so IMHO you should use `Abort` as it's simpler and more readable.